# Inductance of distributed air gapped core

Tags: inductance, magnetics, core

I have got two sets of E70/33/32 core of N87 material, one set with centered airgap of 8mm and another set is un-gapped core. I measured the inductance for N number of turns with centered gapped core and also I measured the inductance with 4mm airgap in the each leg (which gives effective airgap of 8mm). But I am getting different inductance value in both cases, for higher number of turns I am getting difference of 1 to 1.5uH.
I am getting more inductance for distributed gapped core. I do not understand the reason behind it. I designed my own coil former(bobbin) just to give 4mm airgap in each leg and also tried putting a plastic of 4mm on each leg and measured it but the inductance is different in both the cases.
I would want to go with distributed air gap because of its advantage. But I would like to know what is the reason to have different inductances in both the case.
If anyone has experienced this please let me know.
[image]

Comment: The difference value is not helpful. Please give absolute values of inductance - people here learned to do subtraction many years ago. Please also be absolutely clear about the two experiments. You have two cores and one with a centre ground down by 8 mm. You do one test then you use the same cores (because you only have two) and increase the gap all-round by 4mm - this is how it reads!

Comment: Bobbins generally (and specifically) do not create an air-gap - another anomaly that needs clearing up. Pictures/diagrams will really help.

Comment: well, The one with centred 8mm gap (4mm gap on each side) with 7 no of turn gives 8.5uH. The 4mm gap on each leg with 7 no of turns gives 10.4uH. Which picture do you need? Bobbins or Cores?

Comment: *The one with centred 8mm gap (4mm gap on each side)* - what precisely does this mean??? And, how is that different to *The 4mm gap on each leg*. Please don't be ambiguous.

Comment: I attached a picture, g=4mm on both sides so total 8mm. Another Inductor which I tested has 4mm on each leg. Please do not say u did not understand

Comment: Oh you mean 4mm taken from each centre leg. OK, next, where did you apply the windings and is the core dimensions as shown in the picture?

Comment: In both cases i applied on the bobbins. Since I am using 4.3mm litz wire, maximum no of turns I can do in first layer is 7 turn which fills the window area.

Comment: Bobbin - didn't I ask for that detail earlier? Address all the points please if you want to maximize the chances of a decent response.

Answer (score 0):

The E core is gapped in the centre which is series inductance to the much larger main inductance.

Making a gap to an ungapped E core reduces both significantly. Thus you cannot expect the same values for gapping 1 vs 3 legs.

Comment: I did not completely understand it. Could you mention what might be the effect of this? Is there any particular reason?

Comment: The total areas between the gaps are different for the centre vs all 3 interfaces. Thus you would have to reduce the gap to match